# ¿Como deshabilitar la inyección de css en vue-chartjs?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

// Disable automatic style injection
Chart.platform.disableCSSInjection = true;

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html

Como realizar la anterior instrucción la cual es para Chart.js pero quiero implementarla en la libreria de vue-chartjs.

https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/

Comment: Hola Uver, ¿puedes colocar el código relacionado a tu pregunta?

Por otra parte, te invito a realizar un recorrido en [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). También puedes consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para deshabilitar CSS Injection en **vue-chartjs** puedes agregar `default: {disableCSSInjection:true}` a options.

Sería algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
import {Bar} from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  props: {
    chartdata: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: {disableCSSInjection:true}
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
  }
}
```

Esto deberia ya no insertar CSS en el `head`de tu html.